# Making PHP throw a message back to Javascript after file upload

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making a website with a timeline (like social media), and uploading images now works as desired (well, I still need to sanitize and make checks, but that's not the issue here).

My main file has this code for uploading by calling a PHP-file and sending the upload data to this PHP-file:

```
// CALL PHP FILE, UPLOAD MULTIPLE FILES
const url = 'subs/timeline/newTopic.php';

const filesUpload = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
const formData = new FormData();

for (let ii = 0; ii < filesUpload.length; ii++) {
  let file = filesUpload[ii];
  formData.append('filesUpload[]', file);
}

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}); 

alert("Message from PHP");
```

newTopic.php works as it should; and I know I can use print() or echo() for sending a message back to Javascript, but how do I make my alert in the end throw a message from newTopic.php?

Comment: Replace `console.log(response)` inside the `then` callback with `alert(response)`, and make your PHP script output the correct response to begin with …? Or, if you need multiple values - you want to display one thing as alert, log another one to console - then make your PHP script return these values as JSON, so that you can fish them out of there.

Comment: CBroe > I tried replacing the console.log(response); with alert(response) but my alert says [object Response]. Inspect > Console in Chrome reveals that the object does not contain the test string I output from my newTopic.php

Comment: @jakobdam: Your code is already logging the response to the console.  Anything you want to do with that response, that's where you'd do it.  It's not really clear to me what the actual problem is here.

Comment: @David - I want to get the message I've written in my newTopic.php file. The console.log(response) shows the entire object in my console log, which is good - but in that object, I can't seem to find the message I throw in newTopic.php (fx. print("testing"); )

Comment: @jakobdam: When you check the network tab in your browser’s debugging tools, does the response contain that message?

Comment: @David - yes it does, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @jakobdam: Hmm... It’s been a while since I’ve used fetch, but take a look at the examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch  It seems you may need to return a call to response.json() and use it’s result in another .then() afterward.  Basically getting the AJAX response is one async operation, reading it is another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the response body in fetch (I’ll assume it’s JSON for this purpose) is a second asynchronous operation.  Something like this:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
}).then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

*Edit:* Based on comments, the response is text instead of JSON.  In that case the process is still the same, just calling a different function:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
}).then(response => {
  return response.text();
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried implementing the code but the console throws this error:

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: @jakobdam if you don't send JSON from PHP but regular text or nothing then you need to use `return response.text()`.

Comment: @jcubic - That was exactly the problem - I didn't send as JSON, and in my tests with response.text I'd forgotten the () in the end; i.e. response.text()  -- and then I can fetch the object's data.

Thanks - I've made it work now exactly as planned, see my solution posted a few minutes ago...

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot sandwhich...

In my tests, I wrote response.text without the () -- so response.text() gave me the object with the variable. To get the variable I throw in PHP, I simply needed to run a funtion(data) and voila...

The script now looks like this and works as indented:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
}).then(response => {
    response.text().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
});
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me this stupid problem, which would probably have been solved much sooner if I wasn't so ... hmm I forgot what the name for that is... ah nvm...